# "Couldn't match type ‘[]’ with ‘IO’" error in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, type-mismatch, io-monad, do-notation

I am trying to make a list with Points (a datatype that I created), the idea is add an element in each iteration. Something is wrong.

I have tried to put `p` out of `myLoop` but it doesn't seems to work either.

```hs
main = myLoop 
myLoop  = do 
            let p = []
            done <- isEOF
            if done
              then putStrLn ""
              else do inp <- getLine
                      let (label:coord) = words inp
                      p ++  [Point label (map getFloat coord)]
                      -- print (pointerList)
                      myLoop
```

I am getting this output

```
trabalho.hs:30:23: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[]’ with ‘IO’
      Expected type: IO Point
        Actual type: [Point]
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        p ++ [Point label (map getFloat coord)]
      In the expression:
        do inp <- getLine
           let (label : coord) = words inp
           p ++ [Point label (map getFloat coord)]
           myLoop
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        if done then
            putStrLn ""
        else
            do inp <- getLine
               let (label : coord) = ...
               p ++ [Point label (map getFloat coord)]
               ....
   |
30 |                       p ++  [Point label (map getFloat coord)]
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Variable in Haskell are immutable. You can't change their value during program run. Use recursion instead.

Comment: `p ++ […]` doesn't change `p`. It creates a new list. And because that happens in a `do` block with return type `IO`, the compiler complains that it's a list not an IO action. Give `myLoop` a list parameter, call it initially with the empty list in `main`, and append to it before passing the new list to the recursive call.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, do-notation is syntactic sugar with the following rules:

```
do x <- mA
   mB
```

roughly* desugars to `mA >>= \x -> do mB`, where `mA` has type `Monad m => m a` and `do mB` has type `Monad m => m b` for some types `m`, `a`, and `b`.

```
do mA
   mB
```

desugars to `mA >> do mB`, where `mA` has type `Monad m => m a` and `do mB` has type `Monad m => m b` for some types `m`, `a`, and `b`.

```
do a
```

desugars to `a`.

`main` is a special name that represents the entrypoint of the program, and it has type `IO a` for some type `a`. Because you define `main = myLoop`, `myLoop` must also have type `IO a`.

Therefore, in your `myLoop` function:

```
myLoop  = do 
            let p = []
            done <- isEOF
            if done
              then putStrLn ""
              else do inp <- getLine
                      let (label:coord) = words inp
                      p ++  [Point label (map getFloat coord)]
                      -- print (pointerList)
                      myLoop
```

the `do`-block is working with the type `m` = `IO`. Therefore, when you write `p ++  [Point label (map getFloat coord)]`, the typechecker expects a value of type `IO c`, for some type `c`.

However, `p ++  [Point label (map getFloat coord)]` has type `[Point]`, resulting in the type error `Cannot match type '[]' with 'IO'`.

As the type mismatch indicates, your code does not make sense. I assume that you want to append `Point label (map getFloat coord)` to `p`. `++` does *not* mutate `p`; it *creates a new list!* Idiomatic Haskell uses recursion to achieve what you want. The most direct way of fixing your code would be to do the following:

```
main = myLoop []
myLoop p = do
    done <- isEOF
    if done
    then putStrLn ""
    else do inp <- getLine 
            let (label:coord) = words inp
            let p' = p ++  [Point label (map getFloat coord)]
            myLoop  p'
```

Here, `myLoop` takes `p` as a parameter and recursively passes an updated `p` to itself after reading input. `main` calls `myLoop` with an argument of `[]`, which is the initial value of `p`.

The Haskell Wikibook has [a good explanation of do-notation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_notation). In general, I would recommend reading the Haskell Wikibook to better understand Haskell.

*I say "roughly" because these aren't the exact rules. The Wikibook article explains do-notation in depth.

Comment: after fixing it, maybe comment on how `p` isn't used at all in the end, and fixing *that*, the algorithms is quadratic. probable fixes: cons-and-reverse; using difference list (`(xs ++)`) encoding instead of plain `++`; or restructure the `do` block to non-tail-recursive, `sequence`-like structure (`getPoints =~ [ p:ps | p <- getLine, ps <- getPoints`, writing with "monad comprehensions" for brevity).